# How to generate a symbolic multivariate polynomial of a given dimension in SymPy?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, polynomial-math, power-series

I want to use power series to approximate some PDEs. The first step I need to generate symbolic multivariate polynomials, given a numpy ndarray.

Consider the polynomial below:

[image]

I want to take a `m` dimensional `ndarray` of `D=[d1,...,dm]` where `dj`s are non-negative integers, and generate a symbolic multivariate polynomial in the form of symbolic expression. The symbolic expression consists of monomials of the form:

[image]

Fo example if `D=[2,3]` the output should be

[image]

For this specific case I could nest two `for loops` and add the expressions. But I don't know what to do for `D`s with arbitrary length. If I could generate the `D` dimensional ndarrays of `A` and `X` without using for loops, then I could use  `np.sum(np.multiply(A,X))` as [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product) to get what I need.

Comment: [similar question here on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-does-one-generate-algorithmically-all-the-terms-of-a-multivariate-polynomial)

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`symarray`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.dense.symarray) and [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for this:

```
from sympy import *
import itertools
D = (3, 4, 2, 3)
a = symarray("a", D)
x = symarray("x", len(D))
prod_iterator = itertools.product(*map(range, D))
result = Add(*[a[p]*Mul(*[v**d for v, d in zip(x, p)]) for p in prod_iterator])
```

The result being

```
a_0_0_0_0 + a_0_0_0_1*x_3 + a_0_0_0_2*x_3**2 + a_0_0_1_0*x_2 + a_0_0_1_1*x_2*x_3 + a_0_0_1_2*x_2*x_3**2 + a_0_1_0_0*x_1 + a_0_1_0_1*x_1*x_3 + a_0_1_0_2*x_1*x_3**2 + a_0_1_1_0*x_1*x_2 + a_0_1_1_1*x_1*x_2*x_3 + a_0_1_1_2*x_1*x_2*x_3**2 + a_0_2_0_0*x_1**2 + a_0_2_0_1*x_1**2*x_3 + a_0_2_0_2*x_1**2*x_3**2 + a_0_2_1_0*x_1**2*x_2 + a_0_2_1_1*x_1**2*x_2*x_3 + a_0_2_1_2*x_1**2*x_2*x_3**2 + a_0_3_0_0*x_1**3 + a_0_3_0_1*x_1**3*x_3 + a_0_3_0_2*x_1**3*x_3**2 + a_0_3_1_0*x_1**3*x_2 + a_0_3_1_1*x_1**3*x_2*x_3 + a_0_3_1_2*x_1**3*x_2*x_3**2 + a_1_0_0_0*x_0 + a_1_0_0_1*x_0*x_3 + a_1_0_0_2*x_0*x_3**2 + a_1_0_1_0*x_0*x_2 + a_1_0_1_1*x_0*x_2*x_3 + a_1_0_1_2*x_0*x_2*x_3**2 + a_1_1_0_0*x_0*x_1 + a_1_1_0_1*x_0*x_1*x_3 + a_1_1_0_2*x_0*x_1*x_3**2 + a_1_1_1_0*x_0*x_1*x_2 + a_1_1_1_1*x_0*x_1*x_2*x_3 + a_1_1_1_2*x_0*x_1*x_2*x_3**2 + a_1_2_0_0*x_0*x_1**2 + a_1_2_0_1*x_0*x_1**2*x_3 + a_1_2_0_2*x_0*x_1**2*x_3**2 + a_1_2_1_0*x_0*x_1**2*x_2 + a_1_2_1_1*x_0*x_1**2*x_2*x_3 + a_1_2_1_2*x_0*x_1**2*x_2*x_3**2 + a_1_3_0_0*x_0*x_1**3 + a_1_3_0_1*x_0*x_1**3*x_3 + a_1_3_0_2*x_0*x_1**3*x_3**2 + a_1_3_1_0*x_0*x_1**3*x_2 + a_1_3_1_1*x_0*x_1**3*x_2*x_3 + a_1_3_1_2*x_0*x_1**3*x_2*x_3**2 + a_2_0_0_0*x_0**2 + a_2_0_0_1*x_0**2*x_3 + a_2_0_0_2*x_0**2*x_3**2 + a_2_0_1_0*x_0**2*x_2 + a_2_0_1_1*x_0**2*x_2*x_3 + a_2_0_1_2*x_0**2*x_2*x_3**2 + a_2_1_0_0*x_0**2*x_1 + a_2_1_0_1*x_0**2*x_1*x_3 + a_2_1_0_2*x_0**2*x_1*x_3**2 + a_2_1_1_0*x_0**2*x_1*x_2 + a_2_1_1_1*x_0**2*x_1*x_2*x_3 + a_2_1_1_2*x_0**2*x_1*x_2*x_3**2 + a_2_2_0_0*x_0**2*x_1**2 + a_2_2_0_1*x_0**2*x_1**2*x_3 + a_2_2_0_2*x_0**2*x_1**2*x_3**2 + a_2_2_1_0*x_0**2*x_1**2*x_2 + a_2_2_1_1*x_0**2*x_1**2*x_2*x_3 + a_2_2_1_2*x_0**2*x_1**2*x_2*x_3**2 + a_2_3_0_0*x_0**2*x_1**3 + a_2_3_0_1*x_0**2*x_1**3*x_3 + a_2_3_0_2*x_0**2*x_1**3*x_3**2 + a_2_3_1_0*x_0**2*x_1**3*x_2 + a_2_3_1_1*x_0**2*x_1**3*x_2*x_3 + a_2_3_1_2*x_0**2*x_1**3*x_2*x_3**2
```

Remarks:

1. `symarray` depends on `NumPy`, but this does not seem to be an issue for you. If it was, I would create symbols one by one using `itertools.product`
2. The format `Add(*[...])` is more efficient than `sum([...])` for forming symbolic sums with a large number of terms, see [SymPy issue 13945](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/13945).

Comment: great. I'm gonna check it out and come back. in the meantime others are also offering solutions [here](https://gist.github.com/celliern/c715151a247dbb3c8caec15aeb9af83d) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sympy/V4KRzA-3doI). you may like to see them too.

Comment: From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51636453/4999991) I found the `product(*map(range, D))` which seems to be faster than `product(*[range(d) for d in D])`. How do you think?

Comment: Sure, that's a nicer way. Won't make a noticeable difference for the overall thing, because the formation of `prod_iterator` is not the bottleneck here.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could take a loo at my follow up question [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/95886/algorithm-for-using-power-series-to-numerically-solve-a-partial-differential-equ)