# using itertools to generate the Cartesian product of list of lists

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm trying to solve the problem mentioned in [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sympy/V4KRzA-3doI). Consider the `D=[d1,...,dm]` a list of non-negative integers. I want to have the set of the Cartesian products of `range(d1),...,range(dm)`. For example if `m=3` I could use itertools:

```
 indices=[i for i in itertools.product(range(d1),range(d2),range(d3))]
```

I would appreciate if you could help me know how I can generate the `indices` using `D` with arbitrary length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map` to map all items of `D` to `range` and then unpack them for `product`:

```
indices=list(itertools.product(*map(range, D)))
```

Comment: Does `product(*[range(d) for d in D])` deliver the same result as `product(*map(range, D))`? If yes which one is better and why? If not what is the difference?

Comment: They do the same thing, but `map` is generally faster than list comprehension for mapping simple built-in functions (functions implemented in C), while list comprehension is faster in most other cases. List comprehension is also generally more readable unless it's a simple function mapping, which is the case here.

Comment: how to modify this code if D contains multiple lists?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `*` for this:

```
[i for i in itertools.product(*map(range, D))]
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I compared the suggested solutions and the other one was faster.